# Angular karma rebuild trigger file

Tags: angular

I am having an issue with my Angular (16) tests where it seems to be regenerating the application bundle multiple times in a row, despite the fact that I am not even touching the mouse or keyboard. It continuously outputs lines with "Browser application bundle generation complete." immediately after completing the "ng test" command and running the tests.

[image]

My guess is that it is caused by some file being watched that probably shouldn't be, but as I haven't changed the configuration recently, I have no idea which file this could be. So my question is if there is any way to log or debug which file has triggered an application rebuild?

I have tried is to set the karma logLevel to LOG_DEBUG but that gave me nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found this issue on the angular project: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10935

Where they describe an approach to finding the file that triggered a change. The code in the issue is somewhat outdated as it is from an older Angular version, but I found the equivalent for Angular 16 in the file located at **node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/webpack/plugins/karma/karma.js**

On line 138 you can change this

```
compiler.hooks.invalid.tap('karma', () => handler());
```

To this:

```
compiler.hooks.invalid.tap('karma', (arg) => {
    console.log('### CHANGED', arg);
    handler()
});
```

And you will get a console line when a file changes.

That was the answer to my post.

The root issue was that, as I suspected, some files were watched that should not be.

It turns out it was both the .git folder and .angular folder being watched. I was a bit puzzled about this as they should never be watched.

I then found that in my angular.json I had the **sourceRoot** property pointing to just "." which it should not. Instead I changed it to point to "src".

With this change my problem has been solved!

I hope this helps someone else.